# Solve the following matrix equation.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

So I tried to solve this matrix and I got that X has no solutions: $$\begin{pmatrix}
i &-i \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}X^2\begin{pmatrix}
-i &i \\ 
1& 0
\end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix}
1 &i \\ 
0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}$$
 Can you tell me if I am right or not?
Ok so I did multiply that with the inverses of those matrices and I got that $X=\begin{pmatrix}
 a&b \\ 
c &d 
\end{pmatrix}=>X^2=\begin{pmatrix}
a^2+bc &ab+bd \\ 
 ac+cd& bc+d^2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1+i& 2i-1\\ 
 1& i
\end{pmatrix}=A=>AX=XA=>b=c(2i-1);a=c+d$

if we substitute what we got in $X^2=A$ and we do some operations and solve that system we get that $-3c^4-2c^2+1+i(8c^4-4c^2)=0
$ which is 0 if the real part and the imaginary part are 0 so we solve the system $-3c^4-2c^2+1=0$ and $8c^4-4c^2=0$ which has no solution. Am I right?

Comment: How 'bout you tell us the approach you used, and show some details? Then we can help you better understand what you did wrong (or right).

Comment: @JohnHughes I edited the description with what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as $AX^2 B = C$, then $X^2 = A^{-1} C B^{-1} = D=\begin{bmatrix} 1+i & -1+2i \\ 1 & i\end{bmatrix}$.

$D$ has distinct eigenvalues, hence is diagonalisable, hence it has a (not
unique)
square root $X$ such that $X^2  = D$.